# Return Parent Document Elements when Performing Subdocument Query in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My db looks something like this...

```
[ 
  { School: "Princeton",
    Classes: [ {
       Code: "CSC131",
       Teachers: [{
          Name: "Brown",
          Reviews: [{
             _id: "123123123"
             Difficulty: "very hard"
             (etc...)
          }]
       }]
   }]
 }
]
```

There will be many documents in each array in the db, but for the sake of simplicity I have only included one school, class, teacher, and review. This is exactly what I would like the query to return as well. My query looks like this:

```
Schools.find(
        {
          "Classes.Teachers.Reviews": { $elemMatch: { _id: usersReview } },
        },
        { "Classes.Teachers.Reviews.$": 1 }
      )
```

This works alright even though I have to loop through each class to check if the id matches the id given, but does not return the School name and also returns all the different teachers for each class and their reviews as well. I would like it to return exactly what my example db shows above. I would like to still have the School, Class Code, Teacher Name, and Review all returned. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: find returns the top level document unless you lift a child to top level via projection.

Comment: @D.SM Wow. That was easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!